# Register custom app as default for handling sms sending and receveing

Tags: windows-phone-7

Register custom app as default for handling sms sending and receveing in windows phone

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with the current Windows Phone SDK. You can vote on the official Windows Phone Dev Feedback to indicate your interest in an [SMS Access API](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/1901813-sms-access-api).

The only thing you can do with the current SDK is launch the default SMS app with a predefined number and text:

```
SmsComposeTask smsComposeTask = new SmsComposeTask();
smsComposeTask.To = "2065550123";
smsComposeTask.Body = "Your text";
smsComposeTask.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send SMS using the above mentioned method.But you cannot receive SMS in windows phone.
It is possible only in Windows Mobile platforms.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, you cannot change the default apps in Windows Phone.

Answer (score 0):

And addition. You'r program is being run in a sandbox - closed space for you'r application only. That means you cannot run/modify etc other 3 party programms. Only the default programs like Calculator and etc. are awailable